# Have python loop through log files and find string from each one

Tags: loops, python-3.x, filesystems

How can I get Python to loop through a directory and find a specific string in each file located within that directory, then output a summary of what it found?

I want to search the long files for the power status (HOST_POWER), which is either "ON" or "OFF".

```
<GET_HOST_POWER
    HOST_POWER="ON"
    />
```

**Here is what I have so far:**

```
import glob
import os

print("The following list contains the power status of each server.\n")

os.chdir( "LOGS\\" )
for file in glob.glob('*.log'):
    with open(file) as f:
        contents = f.read()
    if 'HOST_POWER="ON"' in contents:
        print (file + " = ON")
    if 'HOST_POWER="OFF"' in contents:
        print (file + " = OFF")
```

Output:

```
The following list contains the power status of each server.

server1.web.com.log = ON
server2.web.com.log = ON
server3.web.com.log = ON
server4.web.com.log = OFF
server5.web.com.log = ON
```

This is working perfectly now, except how can I remove the ".log" from each line so it makes more sense to other users?

---

**More info about what I'm trying to do:**

I have a series of log files located here:

LOGS\

In the "logs" directory, I have a bunch of log files like the following:

```
server1.web.com.log
server2.web.com.log
server3.web.com.log
server4.web.com.log
server5.web.com.log
```

Each log file contains information like the following:

```
IP Address is: server1.web.com <?xml version="1.0"?> <RIBCL VERSION="2.22"> <RESPONSE
    STATUS="0x0000"
    MESSAGE='No error'
     /> </RIBCL> <?xml version="1.0"?> <RIBCL VERSION="2.22"> <RESPONSE
    STATUS="0x0000"
    MESSAGE='No error'
     /> </RIBCL> <?xml version="1.0"?> <RIBCL VERSION="2.22"> <RESPONSE
    STATUS="0x0000"
    MESSAGE='No error'
     /> </RIBCL> <?xml version="1.0"?> <RIBCL VERSION="2.22"> <RESPONSE
    STATUS="0x0000"
    MESSAGE='No error'
     /> <GET_HOST_POWER
    HOST_POWER="ON"
    /> </RIBCL> <?xml version="1.0"?> <RIBCL VERSION="2.22"> <RESPONSE
    STATUS="0x0000"
    MESSAGE='No error'
     /> </RIBCL> <?xml version="1.0"?> <RIBCL VERSION="2.22"> <RESPONSE
    STATUS="0x0000"
    MESSAGE='No error'
     /> </RIBCL> <?xml version="1.0"?> <RIBCL VERSION="2.22"> <RESPONSE
    STATUS="0x0000"
    MESSAGE='No error'
     /> </RIBCL>

iLO_config_utility\cpqlocfg.exe: Script succeeded on "server1.web.com:443"
```

I want my Python code to loop through each log file and find the status of the host power:

```
<GET_HOST_POWER
    HOST_POWER="ON"
    />
```

It could be either "HOST_POWER="ON" or "HOST_POWER="OFF"

Then compile a summary like the following:

```
server1.web.com = ON
server2.web.com = ON
server3.web.com = OFF
server4.web.com = ON
server5.web.com = ON
```

Comment: possible mistake (syntax wise): you should either use `os.chdir( r"LOGS\" )` or `os.chdir( "LOGS\\" )`, as ` \ ` needs to be escaped. this is most likely not the entire solution, but it is what is making the syntax highlighting here kinda funky.

Comment: I added the escape character. Thanks!

Comment: If you're familiar with regular expressions, this is easy. If not, it's still very simple with [`endswith`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) and string slicing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `print` calls, change `file` to `file[:-4]`.  This slices out everything except the last 4 chars, '.log'.